# "Attempt to read or write Protected Memory" error in command line, but not when run through visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, gdal

I have a C# command line application and if I run it while in Visual Studio it runs fine (debug or release, x86).  If I open a command prompt and run the executable that was built while debugging it in I receive an "Attempt to read or write Protected Memory" exception error.

Has anyone else ever run into a problem where an application runs fine in VS, but not via the command line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question would be hard to answer without knowing more about the specific application throwing the exception. Can you provide any code to help us help you?

Comment: Note that the system heap behavior changes if the program is run under a debugger. That may be what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to open an erdas imagine file using the GDAL library.  
`Dataset ds = Gdal.Open(FileName, Access.GA_ReadOnly);`  
Then when I try to access any of it's attribute I get the System.AccessViolationException error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's because gdal has some issues with .NET 4.0.  It seems to work fine with .NET 3.5 and that's all we need for our project.  We might be using an old version of gdal as well. http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4049

It would be nice to know why it runs fine within VS and generates an exception outside though.

Comment: Because there is some undefined behavior being triggered by the 'issues with .NET 4.0'.  In different environments ( debugger, command line ) the undefined behavior takes different forms, one of which, apparently, is crashing.  Which is actually lucky because you might not have found this bug until a customer deployed your app on a platform on which it did crash.